# How to build a (sparse) matrix from SimpleNamespace objects?

Tags: python, scipy, namespaces, sparse-matrix, heatmap

I have a list P of SimpleNamespace objects. The third element of P might look like this:

```
namespace(idx=2, values=[(0, 6), (4, 25), (7, 40), (11, 44), (13, 46), (20, 53)])
```

I want to create an otherwise-0 matrix which takes value `idx` at all coordinates given by the tuples in `values` (aka matrix element at row 4, column 25 is 2) to ultimately feed it into a heatmap. What is the most **pythonic** way to do this?

Extracting the tuples and idx in a nested loop seems like a waste of the SimpleNamespace type. And creating a sparse matrix like dok_matrix isn't that advantageous anyway because then you have to convert to a proper matrix for the heatmap (?)

**edit:** My attempt (which is cumbersome and throws an error bc heatmap won't take dok_matrix)

```
from scipy.sparse import dok_matrix
import seaborn as sns

#P is a list of namespaces as shown above   
S = dok_matrix((10000, 10000), dtype=np.int32)
for i in range(len(P)):
    no_tuples = len(P[i].values)
    for j in range(no_tuples):
        S[P[i].values[j][0], P[i].values[j][1]] = P[i].idx
sns.heatmap(S)
```

Comment: What's special about `SimpleNameSpace` and `heatmap`.  `scipy.sparse` has tried make conversion among its different formats as streamlined as possible.  For a start I'd focus on collecting the kinds of arrays that `coo_matrix` accepts - your `idx` goes into the `data` attribute (with replications),  The coordinates will be split between the `cols` and `rows` attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a `coo` matrix from the sample you give:

```
In [95]: from scipy import sparse

In [96]: idx = 2; values=[(0, 6), (4, 25), (7, 40), (11, 44), (13, 46), (20, 53)]

In [97]: data,row,col = [],[],[]

In [98]: row1,col1 = list(zip(*values))    
In [99]: row1
Out[99]: (0, 4, 7, 11, 13, 20)

In [101]: data.extend([idx for _ in range(len(row1))]) 
# or [idx]*len(row1)   
In [102]: row.extend(row1)    
In [103]: col.extend(col1)
```

Repeat this for all Namespaces.

```
In [104]: M = sparse.coo_matrix((data, (row, col)))
In [105]: M
Out[105]: 
<21x54 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 6 stored elements in COOrdinate format>

In [106]: M.A
Out[106]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       ...,
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 2]])

In [107]: M.data
Out[107]: array([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])
```